# Lightbox jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, lightbox

It won't let me answer my own question, but the problem has been solved. It was a brackets issue *facepalm*

Comment: Your issue is with `.live()` because it's been removed in jQuery 2.0.

Comment: `{);` change this to `});` and try once

Comment: Change .live() to .on() as described by Sridhar below; changed {); to }); (thank you! didn't catch that at all); made Sridhar's changes to the div. Still nothing!

Comment: False alarm -- I figured it out after I saw that backwards-facing end tag (thanks, Dotnet): I was missing a "{" at the end of the line starting with "if." Thank you, everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Try with `On()`

```
$('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function(){
$('#lightbox').hide();
});

 <div id="trigger">
        <a class="lightbox_trigger" href="media/trigger_small.png">
        </a>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/62ynF/)

Comment: Not doing anything :-/ To clarify: the part I'm having trouble with right now is that when I click the image (trigger_small.png), I get brought right to "Why.html" and absolutely nothing happens with the lightbox I've been trying to create.

Comment: probelm is you give href link so it goes to that page

Comment: I fixed the end of the code as you suggested, and changed the href to the trigger image (though I kept the <img> tag inside)... but now it just opens up that image instead.

Comment: then what do want to achieve

Comment: False alarm -- I figured it out after I saw that backwards-facing end tag (thanks, Dotnet): I was missing a "{" at the end of the line starting with "if." Thank you, everybody!